# How to write files in hidden mode on SD card in Android

Tags: android, android-file

I would like to be able to write files in hidden mode or hide files in a folder the on SD card in Android. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve by "hiding" files on the card? preventing against accidental deletion? steganography? idle curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the file with a '.' before the name ? As android is based on linux it could work

Comment: This is not really "hidden", so much as tools such as `ls(1)` won't show it by convention.

Comment: this could be a solution, till he does not find a proper way to hidden a file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually sd cards are vfat (fat32) so that filesystem does support various attributes including read-only and hidden.

However, you can't set them from android unless you are willing to use native code.